# Cygwin or Gnuwin - Find .txt files named* copy & paste to specific directory

Tags: find, cygwin, cp

Okay so I want to know how I would go about doing this, using grep to locate .txt files named "cocacola1", "cocacola2", "cocacola3" & then copying them to another directory. So searching for files named "cocacola" &/even if it contains other characters within the file name to then copy them to another directory/location.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use unix `find`. Assuming the files you're searching for are in 'source' and you want to copy to 'destination':

```
find source -name '*cocacola*' -exec cp {} destination \;
```

I put the wildcard '*' before and after cocacola since you said other characters might exist in the file name.

Comment: It's because once find copies the files, in the search it will spot these files again and try to re-copy them. But then it realises it's the same file so it complains. If you want to avoid it, try to exclude your destination from your search path.

Comment: Hmm not really want I'm looking for " destination " outputs to one single file, I just want the original files containing cocacola.txt from C:/ to R:/

Comment: What do you mean? I just tried it on command line. Assuming source is C: and R: is destination it copies all the cocacola files from C: to R:

Comment: okay I got it working but is there anyway to rename duplicates, so say C:/ contains cocacola1.txt but C:/users/ contains cocacola1.txt is there anyway to rename them so they both copy?

Comment: @ThomasBishop You can use the `--backup=numbered` option with `cp`, it will make automatic backup of existing files